# Position vector and vector joining 2 points

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Let us consider 2 point $A(1,2)$ and $B(2,1)$. The vector joining the two points directed from A to B is $\textbf{i}-\textbf{j}$, but that vector is the same as the position vector of the point $P(1,-1)$.

So what is the difference ? I mean they have different location in coordinate plane but they have same vectors

Answer (score 0):

A position vector $\textbf{r}$ denotes the position of a point relative to origin. The vector difference between two points $\textbf{v}_1 - \textbf{v}_2$ is the direction and distance you would need to travel if you were at position $\textbf{v}_2$ to reach position $\textbf{v}_1$